# Qual a diferença entre Eloquent\Model::get() e Eloquent\Model::all()?

Tags: laravel-eloquent

- Qual a diferença em usar `Model::get()` e `Model::all()`?
- Algum deles é mais recomendado para trazer todos os registros do banco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tudo é `get()`, ou seja, o método `all()` do `Model` chama `get()`, código que exemplifica a afirmação:

```php
public static function all($columns = ['*'])
{
    $columns = is_array($columns) ? $columns : func_get_args();

    $instance = new static;

    return $instance->newQuery()->get($columns);
}
```

outro ponto a dizer é que os retornos trazidos são produzidos pela `Builder` (`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`) que é a classe responsável em construir expressões para dispor *resultados com filtros*, *ordenação*, *paginação*, *seleção de campos de um tabela*, ***etc***. Nesse linha do código `$instance->newQuery()->get($columns);` o `newQuery()` produz uma `Builder`.

Em versões anteriores isso não funcionava assim, tinha uma pequena diferença onde `get` não funciona no `model`, somente `all`, mas, o retorno quem fazia era o `Builder` com o método `get` e houve uma unificação para facilitar o manuseio dessas operações que produz o mesmo resultado.

Outro ponto quanto se parte para construção de expressão o método é o `get` o `all` não existe porque como já foi dito o método `all` faz parte do `Model`.